# Clear cache of list of apps

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app which clears cache of multiple apps. I know the cache of the current app can be cleared and it is pretty straight forward using the code below

```
public void clearCache() {
Log.i(TAG, "Clearing Cache.");
File[] dir = mContext.getCacheDir().listFiles();
if(dir != null){
    for (File f : dir){
        f.delete();
    }
   }
}
```

but i cannot find any post which shows or even mentions the task that i want to accomplish  so all i want to know is whether i can clear the cache of another app using its package name.

Thank you.

Comment: Wait? What is the relation with the title? :o

Comment: You question body indicating one thing and title another!

Comment: sorry. I kinda wrote it on the tab where i was about to ask another question. Its updated xD